# git diff --color-words separate removals and additions, get counts of each

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Here's a screenshot of a diff GUI tool that I'd like to replicate from the command line:

[image]

`git diff --color-words` looks promising, but I get both removals and additions together like this:
[image]

1. How can I get removals and additions into separate paragraphs?
2. How can I use highlighting instead of coloring the text?
3. How can I get a count of both the number of removals and additions?

Comment: `git diff --color-words` cannot present its output in the way you want. You have to post-process it with your own tool.